# How to enable Azure Server which is currently disable

Tags: azure, status

I did work with that Azure server a week ago. but currently, it is showing the server disabled. how can I enable that?

Image link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tFEsfF9mwnwsilqMcoEsqxKgSjNpD-jZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am unable to open the link you have provided. Could you please update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a was using the trial version of azure, so I had a limited amount of credit. I was running out of credit that's why my server got Disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your subscription is disabled for some reason because of the following reasons

(i) Your credit is expired

(ii) You reached your spending limit

(iii) Your bill is past due

You can reactivate by following the steps mentioned **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-become-disable)**